# How to improve PostreSQL speed when running tests via test containers

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, testcontainers

I'm attempting to execute integration tests utilizing Spring Boot in conjunction with Testcontainers. However, I've noticed that the database initialization is quite time-consuming. As it stands, a single test takes approximately 40 seconds to finish, including the time it takes to close all connections. The relevant code is structured as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class ApplicationTests {

    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> posgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:16.0-alpine");

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        
    }

}
```

In the logs I can see the following after the test is completed:

[image: Test logs picture]

Given that I'm working on a MacBook M1 Max, I believe there should be sufficient computational resources to expedite the test execution. Does anyone have suggestions for optimizing the duration of such tests? Perhaps there's a specialized Postgres image designed for quicker startup, or certain arguments that could be passed to improve the container's initialization time.

Comment: Are you completely restarting the Postgres image for every single test? Yes, that seems like a great way to take up a lot of time. Have you considered simply clearing the tables or restoring state from a backup?

Comment: first time execution is around that because pulling the image and then start the container. But, second one should be 2 or 3 seconds. Postgres startup is quite fast. At least, on desktop you should not experience more than that. In CI, for example, using GHA will be pulling the image every time. I am talking from the test execution POV and not the whole build process which involves more tasks depending on which one you are using.

Comment: I get ~40 seconds even if I run it several times so the image has been pulled by the time I run the test

Comment: On my M1 Pro single test with PostgreSQL container takes about 17 seconds for small Spring Boot application.
In general startup time depends on size of ApplicationContext and a huge amount of options in application.yaml.
Consider to set server.shutdown=immediate for tests and share a demo project with us.

Comment: out of curiosity, which container runtime are you using? Docker Desktop? Colima? Rancher? Testcontainers Embedded Runtime? Orbstack?

Comment: I also experienced this at some point, @DanyloZatorsky. But just for a single test: the others used just a couple of seconds, and suddenly one took 40 seconds to startup, then another 20 seconds to finish the test. super weird. Unfortunately, after fiddling with Spring Annotations, I got it working again and all 20 db tests finished in 12 seconds.

Comment: You can reuse the database container between tests (instead of shutting it down and starting again). You can reuse the database schema (instead of dropping schema and recreating, just truncate all tables). You can use TmpFS for volume instead of mounting your filesystem.